# Perform logic operations on boolean array values

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

I have an array with boolean values, e.g.

```
$myarray = array(true, false, false, true, false);
```

Now I want to perform some logic operations on my array values, so I get the output:

```
FALSE
```

from my array.

Comment: What should be your desired outcome here ?

Comment: Why var_dump(), and then echo the result returned by var_dump()?

Comment: Interesting, also mentioned here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#104568

Comment: But if you try to echo a boolean false, then PHP displays nothing, so perhaps that is a part of your problem..... but exactly what are you trying to achieve? Do you want an array of `1` and `0` values to match your array values? Or are you simply trying to get the result of ANDing them all together?

Comment: Are you saying you want to logically evaluate those boolean variables, using AND? That's not what implode is for.

Comment: You're wrong, the output of your code is `string(2) "11"`.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? It seems like you're approaching the solution from an incorrect angle. Seems like `implode()` is not the best function to use here.

Comment: @iainn I want multiplied all those together Like to multiplied 1 and 0 equals 0 !!!!

Comment: How do you figure the result should be `false`?

Comment: If you want to apply a logical operator or mathematical operation to every member of an array, then you don't do it using `implode` and then complaining it doesn't work. It **does** work, but it's not the tool you **need**. You want to iterate every element and apply the logical `AND` operation. Don't try to be witty about it, writing extra 3 lines of code for a `for` or `foreach` loop never killed anyone. If you want to be real "classy" about doing this task, you can use `array_map` and map a callback function to every element of the array.

Comment: `$res = array_reduce($myarray, function($carry,$value) { $carry &= $value; return $carry; }, true);`

Comment: @Nabi Just to clear some confusions: Do you want to get the product of all array elements? Means multiplying each value together? Or what exactly do you want? Maybe add another example to your question.

Comment: @Nabi That doesn't help. What do you want to do? Maybe add another example with some other values to your question to show exactly what you want to do

Comment: @Nabi But you know that multiplying does not make much sense for boolean values?! Because to be strict you can't multiply boolean values with each other. You can only do this, because PHP casts them to integers. Are you sure you don't want to preform any logical operations: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php on your array values?

Comment: @Rizier123 ohh, I forgot , because i need to use AND, OR on it , How ?

Comment: @Nabi So you do NOT want to do math operations on your values, but actually logical operations?

Comment: @Rizier123 array_product solves my `AND` clause but what about or ?

Comment: So you actually want to perform logic operations on your booleans?!

Comment: @Nabi Then please unaccept my answer and accept another one. That `array_product()` may work but it clearly isn't what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$res = true;
foreach ($myarray as $item) $res &= $item;
echo var_dump($res);
```

A bit less elegant, but it should work. You'll have an integer in the end because we're using bit logic here, could be improved.

For a `OR` case you could do almost the same thing:

```
$res = true;
foreach ($myarray as $item) $res |= $item;
echo var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to treat booleans as strings, which is fundamentally wrong. What you want is, for example, an *array reduction*:

```
$res = array_reduce($myarray, function ($a, $b) { return $a && $b; }, true);
                                                     // default value ^^^^
```

Or a more efficient short-circuiting `all` function:

```
function all(array $values) {
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        if (!$value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if (all($myarray)) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just search your array for `false`, and if it's present, return `false`, and if not return `true`:

```
$result = (array_search(false, $myarray, true) === false);
```

Since you edited your question, if you want it to return 0 or 1 just do:

```
$result = (array_search(false, $myarray, true) === false) ? 1 : 0;
```